# Spring cloud AWS multiple SimpleMessageListenerContainer configuration setup

Tags: spring-cloud-aws

I am trying to instantiate multiple `SimpleMessageListenerContainer` and define custom `TaskExecutor` for independent `MessageListener` queues, The reason for this setup is I don't want to create a shared `SimpleMessageListenerContainer` where thread pool configuration is shared across all Message Listener queues.

Can you please provide a suggestion? I tried following some of the spring-messaging-aws test case approach but doesn't seem to be working?

```
@Bean
public SimpleMessageListenerContainerFactory simpleMessageListenerContainerFactory() {
    SimpleMessageListenerContainerFactory msgListenerContainerFactory = new SimpleMessageListenerContainerFactory();
    msgListenerContainerFactory.setAmazonSqs(amazonSQSClient());
    return msgListenerContainerFactory;
}

@Bean
public SimpleMessageListenerContainer uplinkMessageListenerContainer() throws Exception {
    SimpleMessageListenerContainer msgListenerContainer = simpleMessageListenerContainerFactory().createSimpleMessageListenerContainer();
    msgListenerContainer.setAmazonSqs(amazonSQSClient());
    QueueMessageHandler messageHandler = new QueueMessageHandler();
    msgListenerContainer.setMessageHandler(messageHandler);
    StaticApplicationContext applicationContext = new StaticApplicationContext();
    applicationContext.registerSingleton("uplinkMessageListener", UplinkMessageListener.class);

    messageHandler.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
    msgListenerContainer.setBeanName("testContainerName");
    messageHandler.afterPropertiesSet();
    msgListenerContainer.setMaxNumberOfMessages(maxNumberOfmessages);
    msgListenerContainer.setWaitTimeOut(waitTimeout);
    msgListenerContainer.setBackOffTime(backOfTime);
    msgListenerContainer.setAutoStartup(sqsAutoStartup);
    msgListenerContainer.setVisibilityTimeout(visibilityTimeout);
    msgListenerContainer.setTaskExecutor(createDefaultTaskExecutor("MPSQSUplinkMessageListener", 2, 10));
    msgListenerContainer.afterPropertiesSet();
    msgListenerContainer.start();
    return msgListenerContainer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a better solution than creating a service with Scheduler.

```
@Component
public class AmazonService {

  @Scheduled("0 */5 * * * *")
  public void checkSqs() {
     // Check sqs
  }
}
```

SQS will be instantiated either by a lazy mechanism or via a constructor in the service.